# The purpose of self

Tags: python, python-unittest

I tried to test a file named **calc.py** using unit testing

```
import unittest
import calc
class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_add(self):
        result = calc.add(10,5)
        self.assertEqual(result,15)
```

What does self refer to in this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Comment: Hm, I forgot I could single-handedly reopen a question. Anyway, I voted to do so because I suspect the question is more along the lines of "Where does the instance of `TestCase` come from?".

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the instance of that invokes the method, in this case an instance of `TestCalc`. However, you never see the instances specifically, unless you write your own test runner. Otherwise, you typically only interact with the instance (aside from calling the various `assert*` methods) if you override `setUp` to configure the fixture.

For example,

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.x = SomeClass()

    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.x.foo(), 3)

    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.x.bar(), 6)
```

`x` is an instance of a class that you want to use in multiple tests. Rather than call `x = SomeClass()` in every test method, you call it once in `setUp` and save the result as an attribute of the test case itself, making it available to each test method.